# Hibernate to handle deleted object using property deleted

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using hibernate as ORM and in my Domain deleting objects is vi setting their `deleted` property. Now I want to make hibernate load only not deleted objects when it loads a one-to-Many relation but I also want to be able to load deleted object vi HQL and `Session.load()`;

what is the best way to do this? i mean i have a lot of relations and i dont whant to put `@filter` on every relation if possible!.

by the way all may entities are subclass of a `BaseObject` class which has the property `deleted`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do BaseDao with `load()` and `loadAll()` methods to address your question.

Answer (score 0):

I thing currently the only way is to use `@Where(clause="deleted = 'true'")` on every `OneToMany` or `ManyToMany` relation.